# Как перевести уравнение, написанное словами, в целое число, с учетом квантификаторов: "squared", "times", "twice"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

У меня есть много строк, таких как: `five hundred thirty-four squared`, `one billion nine hundred twenty-two million three hundred forty-two thousand fifty-five twice`, `eight hundred sixty-four times six hundred ten` и т.д.

Я должен перевести их в числовое значение. Пробовал `word2number` но он не распознает `squared` или `twice` или `sixty-four times` (в этих случаях).

Существует ли какая-нибудь библиотека или иной способ решить проблему?

Comment: а можно заменой слов привести ваши слова к тем, которые поймет библиотека?

Comment: Идея неплохая, библиотека, конечно, вряд ли поймет, но если взять слово например `times` и левую часть умножать на правую и т.д., то неплохо выйдет, но боюсь, что очень много времени займет, вот если бы был способ это легче сделать? @Zhihar

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

Как-то так:

```
import re
import numexpr as ne
from word2number import w2n

tests = [
  "five hundred thirty-four squared", 
  "one billion nine hundred twenty-two million three hundred forty-two thousand fifty-five twice", 
  "eight hundred sixty-four times six hundred ten"
]


word_map = {
  "squared": "**2",
  "twice": "*2",
  "times": "*",
}

def get_number(s, word_map=word_map):
    s = s.casefold()
    pat = r"({})".format("|".join(list(word_map)))
    res = "".join([
        word_map.get(x) if x in word_map else str(w2n.word_to_num(x)) 
        for x in re.split(pat, s)
        if x.strip()
    ])
    return ne.evaluate(res).item()
```

тесты:

```
In [260]: [get_number(x) for x in tests]
Out[260]: [285156, 3844684110, 527040]
```

Comment: Отличное решение, но на практике скорее всего придется еще как-то продумать группировки. [eight times five squared](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eight+times+five+squared), [eight times five all squared](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eight+times+five+all+squared)

Comment: @extrn, полностью согласен, я не претендую на универсальное решение ;)